# Auto height on element with only relatively positioned children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

As you can see [here](http://bramvanroy.be/infoToolTip/) you need to apply a static height to `#wrapper` because else the div won't contain its children. (here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/y5nYN/13/)) This is quite logical. I would want, however, that I can give #wrapper an auto height by which it can contain multiple rows of relatively positioned elements.

I suppose I could add an other wrapper around the individual items and position them staticly? But I would prefer to not add more HTML. If needed a JS/jQuery solution is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an **float** is your child DIV's so you have to clear it's `parent` & remove height from it. write like this:

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 360px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 1008px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/y5nYN/16/

Comment: Interesting, the overflow:hidden; did it. Can you explain why?

Comment: here is the good article about clear floats http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html